# When displaying an image, which of the following two measures should be taken with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote the following code in React.

```js
 const onChangeImage = (e, setState) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            // 画像を格納
            reader.onload = (data) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'SET_SALON_DATA',
                    payload: {
                        title: e.target.name,
                        content: file
                    }
                })
                // this！！
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        }
    }
```

At "this!!" point,which method is better?
This state goes into the url of the img tag.

```
setState(URL.createObjectURL(file))
```

or

```
setState(data.target.result))
```

I'm waiting for your answer!